# Writing "Proof of . . ." cleanly in svjour3

Tags: spacing, theorems, sv-classes

Perhaps I am spoiled by `amsthm`, but I rather like being able to freely rename the proof environment, especially when there are intervening statements.  For example:

Example 1: nice behavior

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[prop]{Lemma}

\begin{document}
\begin{prop} \label{eq:prop1}
 Some proposition.
\end{prop}
We prove the above proposition with the help of the following lemma (see [citation]).
\begin{lem}
A useful lemma.
\end{lem}
\begin{proof}[Proof of Prop.~\ref{eq:prop1}]
This is desired behaviour.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image: A standard environment: the original "proof" is overwritten]

`svjour3`, however, does not have this property.  The `proof` environment as predefined does not omit the original "Proof." text, and puts your addition in parentheses.  My workaround is to have a `proofrename` proof with an empty name, and following their suggestion, to use the `theopargself` environment to omit the parentheses around the optional argument.

Example 2: bad behavior

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[smallextended,envcountsame,envcountsect]{svjour3}    
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\spnewtheorem*{proofrename}{}{\itshape}{\rm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition} \label{prop:prop1}
The \texttt{proof} environment is strange in \texttt{svjour3}.
\end{proposition}
We prove the above proposition with the help of the following lemma (see [citation]).
\begin{lemma}
A useful lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}[Proof of \ref{prop:prop1}, Version 1]
Optional arguments do \textit{not} supersede the ``proof'' statement.  
\end{proof}

\begin{theopargself}
\begin{proofrename}[Proof of \ref{prop:prop1}, Version 2.]
Even suppressing the name, there is still some whitespace.  
\end{proofrename}
\end{theopargself}
\end{document}
```

[image: svjour3 behavior: the proof is not omitting, or there is some whitespace]

Are there any suggestions to get a better `proof` environment?  I know it is possible, because of one of the free articles at the journal I'm considering: see the free article by Z. Ercan at [Positivity](http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/mathematics/journal/11117).

**Note:** I see that most of the other `svjour3` answers use `\def` ; however, the template `LaTeX` file that comes with `svjour3` requests that you eschew `\def` in favor of `\newcommand` .  Therefore, I will prefer answers without `\def`, though I recognize that this may not be possible.

Comment: Try `\begin{theopargself}%` or move the 2nd line to above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using just standard `svjour` commands and exploiting the fact that `\spnewtheorem*{foo}{Foo}{}{}` stores `Foo` as the expansion of `\fooname`:

```
\documentclass[smallextended,envcountsame,envcountsect]{svjour3}
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof

\spnewtheorem*{xproof}{}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}% the label is assigned later
\newcommand\xprooftitle{}
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]
 {\renewcommand\xproofname{#1}\xproof}
 {\endxproof}

\begin{document}
\begin{proposition}\label{prop1}
Some proposition.
\end{proposition}
We prove the above proposition with the help of the following lemma (see [citation]).
\begin{lemma}
A useful lemma.
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}[Proof of Prop.~\ref{prop1}]
This is desired behaviour.\qed
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The advantage of this approach is that if the people at Springer don't like your change to `proof`, they'll just need to remove the five lines above. Mark them clearly in the file with comments specifying what you did:

```
% I redefine the `proof` environment in order that
% \begin{proof}[Proof of the main theorem]
% produces ``Proof of the main theorem'' and not
% ``Proof (Proof of the main theorem)''
\spnewtheorem*{xproof}{}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}% the label is assigned later
\newcommand\xprooftitle{}
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]
 {\renewcommand\xproofname{#1}\xproof}
 {\endxproof}
% Comment the five lines above to restore the default behavior of `proof'
```

Comment: For me, this changes some page breaks. Is there a version where the spacing is the same as with the original (svjour3) proof environment?

Answer (score 2):

In the example below I define a version that behaves like the proof environment from `amsmath`: without optional argument, the label used is "Proof"; in case an optional argument is used, its contents is used (without parentheses) as the label.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[smallextended,envcountsame,envcountsect]{svjour3}    
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{proof}{%
  \def\@Opargbegintheorem#1#2#3#4{#4\trivlist
      \item[]{#3#2\@thmcounterend\ }}%
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{proof}{%
  \def\@Opargbegintheorem#1#2#3#4{#4\trivlist
      \item[\hskip\labelsep{#3#1}]{#3(#2)\@thmcounterend\ }}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition} \label{prop:prop1}
The \texttt{proof} environment is strange in \texttt{svjour3}.
\end{proposition}
We prove the above proposition with the help of the following lemma (see [citation]).
\begin{lemma}
A useful lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
Without optional argument, the standard ``Proof'' label is used.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[Proof of \ref{prop:prop1}, Version 1]
An optional argument supersedes the ``Proof'' label.  
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]